# Ignore special characters in Examine

Tags: c#, umbraco, lucene.net, examine

In Umbraco, I use Examine to search in the website but the content is in french. Everything works fine except when I search for "Français" it's not the same result as "Francais". Is there a way to ignore those french characters? I try to find a FrenchAnalyser for Leucene/Examine but did not found anything. I use Fuzzy so it return results even if the words is not the same.

Here's the code of my search :

```
public static ISearchResults Search(string searchTerm)
        {
            var provider = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ExternalSearcher"];
            var criteria = provider.CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.Or);

            var crawl = criteria.GroupedOr(BoostedSearchableFields, searchTerm.Boost(15))
            .Or().GroupedOr(BoostedSearchableFields, searchTerm.Fuzzy(Fuzziness))
            .Or().GroupedOr(SearchableFields, searchTerm.Fuzzy(Fuzziness))
            .Not().Field("umbracoNavHide", "1");

            return provider.Search(crawl.Compile());
        }
```

Comment: I know I will not be very helpful but, if there is a way, you can transform all special char in a normal char in the content you are searching it.

Comment: not realy, I tought about it already but thanks

Comment: Why can't you do the replacing of the characters? I really don't see any other way. Assuming you have already checked all method overloads..

Comment: The problem is not when I search for "Français" is when I search for "Francais" without the special character. I don't get any result. It looks like the index is built with the specials characters but it should return the result even if I search for the word without the special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using a custom analyer based on the `SnowballAnalyzer`

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : SnowballAnalyzer
{
    public CustomAnalyzer() : base("French") { }

    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        TokenStream result = base.TokenStream(fieldName, reader);

        result = new ISOLatin1AccentFilter(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex like this below:

```
var strInput ="Français";
var strToReplace = string.Empty;
var sNewString = Regex.Replace(strInput, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", strToReplace);
```

I've used this pattern "[^A-Za-z0-9]" to replace all non-alphanumeric string with a blank.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Israel but the problem is the other way around, lucente.net index all the content with the "ç" and when I do a search for "c" I want the results to include those with the "ç".

Answer (score 0):

You can actually convert the unicode characters with diacritics to english equivalents using the following method. That will enable you to search for "Français" with the search term "Francais".

```csharp
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        return text;

    text = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var chars = text.Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray();

    return new string(chars).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Use it on any string like this:

```csharp
var converted = unicodeString.RemoveDiacritics();
```