# Ignore Special Characters (tittles) in Examine search

Tags: c#, lucene, umbraco, examine

Using **Umbraco v6, Examine search (not full blown Lucene queries)**. This is a Latin/South American website. I've asked my colleagues how they type in tittles  (*accent mark over a letter*) for search/URL, and they all said that they don't, they just use "regular" characters (A-Z, a-z).

I know how to strip special characters *OUT* of the string when passing to Examine, but I need the other way around, as in Examine removing the special characters from properties to match to the query. I have numerous "nodes" that have tittles in the name (which is one of the properties that I am searching on).

Posts that I've researched:

- http://shazwazza.com/categories/Examine?p=2
- [Ignore special characters in Examine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312632/ignore-special-characters-in-examine)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/umbraco-dev/W6cWyPOc43Y

I've tried writing the luence query (or so I think) but I'm not getting in any hits.

```
// q is my query from QueryString
var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["CustomSearchSearcher"];

//var query = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria().Field("nodeName", q).Or().Field("description", q).Compile();
//var searchResults = searcher.Search(query).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).TakeWhile(x => x.Score > 0.05f);

var searchResults = searcher.Search(Global.RemoveSpecialCharacters(q), true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).TakeWhile(x => x.Score > 0.05f);
```

Global Class

```
    public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                    || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'z' || (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '_'))
                || str[i] == 'á' || str[i] == 'é' || str[i] == 'í' || str[i] == 'ñ' || str[i] == 'ó' || str[i] == 'ú')
            {
                sb.Append(str[i]);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

As stated above, I need special characters (tittles) removed from Lucene, not the query passed in.

From: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/overview-explanation

I've also read about "Analyzers", but I have never worked with them before, nor know which one(s) to get/install/add to VS, etc. Is that the better way to go about this??

Comment: anyone? I've been researching language analyzers but I do not know how to implement it into my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom analyzer is the answer.

This is answered on the umbraco forum here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/16396-Examine-and-accents-for-portuguese-language

Make a analyzer that strips all special characters:

```
  public class CIAIAnalyser : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, reader);

        tokenizer.SetMaxTokenLength(255);
        TokenStream stream = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
        stream = new LowerCaseFilter(stream);
        return new ASCIIFoldingFilter(stream);

    }

}
```

Then you do the same for the search input.

```
   public class CleanAccent
{
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(string input)
    {
        // Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full canonical decomposition.

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;

        string inputInFormD = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int idx = 0; idx < inputInFormD.Length; idx++)
        {
            UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(inputInFormD[idx]);
            if (uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                sb.Append(inputInFormD[idx]);
            }
        }

        return (sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));
    }

}
```

then reference the analyzer in ExamineSettings.config.

Comment: Excellent find. Thanks so much!

Comment: @PeterSmith do you know how to make this in Umbraco 7?  can't make it work. Parser Error Message: Provider must implement the class 'Examine.Providers.BaseSearchProvider'.